# How to create this container using CustomClipper in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

*Hello, I am not profession in custom design. Can someone help me to achieve this pointed design using `CustomClipper`.*

This following code give me similar result but there is no corner radius at `topLeft` and `topRight` corners.

```
class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
@override
Path getClip(Size size) {

  final flippedPath = Path()
    ..moveTo(0.0, size.height)
    ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
    ..lineTo(size.width * 0.75, 0.0)
    ..lineTo(size.width * 0.25, 0.0)
    ..close();

  return flippedPath;
}

@override
bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
  return false;
}
}
```

[image: ClipPathGround]

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {

    final flippedPath = Path()
      ..moveTo(0.0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width * 0.75, 0.0)
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width * 0.75, 20),
        radius: Radius.circular(20),
        clockwise: false,
      )
      ..arcToPoint(
        Offset(size.width * 0.25, 20),
        radius: Radius.circular(20),
        clockwise: false,
      )
      ..lineTo(size.width * 0.25, 0.0)
      ..close();

    return flippedPath;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but It is not working :-).

Comment: What happen?   why

Comment: It show  broken clip design like the head of bat man ;-)